# Unexpected reserved word: import - Webpack, Babel, Node, React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

After adding SSR to my app, I ended up using some ES6 in my server's index.js file, and now I'm having a problem getting it to run on Heroku again.

I've done a lot of research and understand that using ES6 requires babel to transpile the server file, but pretty much everyone's recommendations I can find typically ended up with requiring the .babelrc file, or specifying/installing the presets, but from what I can tell, I've already done this.

I'm finding that the more I try to troubleshoot this, the more confused I'm becoming, so I wanted to reach out on here for some discussion :) thanks everyone (Full code: https://github.com/trm313/mern-boiler)

**Heroku errors**

```
2017-05-08T14:35:04.470656+00:00 app[web.1]: [32m[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js --presets react,es2015`[39m
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545063+00:00 app[web.1]: You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in Babel 6.
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545069+00:00 app[web.1]: Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the `babel-cli` package.
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545070+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545071+00:00 app[web.1]:     npm uninstall -g babel
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545072+00:00 app[web.1]:     npm install --save-dev babel-cli
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-08T14:35:04.545073+00:00 app[web.1]: See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ for setup instructions.
2017-05-08T14:35:04.554946+00:00 app[web.1]: [31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m
```

Of the following scripts, "npm run start" works fine locally, but fails when uploaded to Heroku. It complains that I need to use the 'babel-cli' package instead of 'babel', which I'm already doing.. (Same for "start-dev")

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-authentication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.3",
    "npm": "4.2.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --use-strict index.js",
    "bundle": "webpack",
    "start-old": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p",
    "start-dev": "babel-node index.js --presets react,es2015",
    "start": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node --presets react,es2015",
    "build": "babel lib -d dist --presets react,es2015",
    "serve": "node dist/index.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "client-sessions": "^0.7.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.17.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.8.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "validator": "^6.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  // the entry file for the bundle
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src/app.js'),

  // the bundle file we will get in the result
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist/js'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },

  module: {

    // apply loaders to files that meet given conditions
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src'),
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ["react", "es2015"]
      }
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  // start Webpack in a watch mode, so Webpack will rebuild the bundle on changes
  watch: false
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
   "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the start script to "node server.js" instead of nodemon.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks I tried that as well, but it failed with the same error

Comment: @trm313 I've looked around alot but can't really find anything. Where do you see the Heroku errors that you posted the image of? Do you get these errors when you try to push your code to heroku master? Try removing "--exec babel-node --presets react,es2015" and see if it makes a difference, otherwise go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/username/activity and have a look at the build log and see if you find anything!

Comment: Thanks for taking a look around. I'm finding that I can't get my app to run even locally if I strip the babel commands (including the presets flag) from the start sequence. This is when I get the "Unexpected reserved word: import" error

However, I can't get heroku to accept the babel commands. When I try I get the babel errors about not using 'babel' anymore. 

The Heroku logs I'm looking in that show the babel errors are from https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<appname>/logs . The activity page shows successful builds, but then the app enters the crashed state

Comment: @trm313 Okay, if you look into the node_modules folder, do you see the folder babel there? Try adding this line to the line above "loader: 'babel-loader'" in your webpack-config file: exclude: /node_modules/

Comment: Checked the node_modules folder - there is no 'babel' folder. I added the 'excude: /node_modules/' line to the webpack.config file and gave it another go, but same results

Comment: I see that there is a 'babel' file located in the node_modules/.bin directory. I have been playing around with running my start command directly from the babel-node file instead (eg. "start": "node_modules/.bin/babel-node index.js --presets react,es2015") and this works fine locally, but I get the same complaint from heroku about switching from babel to babel-cli